# Can we use process.hrtime() as UUID in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, process, uuid, v8

Can we use `process.hrtime()` as universal unique id within the current process ?

```
var uuid = parseInt(process.hrtime().join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process.hrtime()` to create identifiers with low chance of collision, but they are not unique, especially not across application restarts (which matters if you persist any of them to a database or similar), and not when several threads/processes/instances are involved.

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time):

> These times are relative to an arbitrary time in the past, and not related to the time of day

Also, by using `parseInt(....join(''))`, you are introducing a second way for collisions to happen: e.g. `[1, 23]` and `[12, 3]` will lead to the same result.

If you want to build your own solution (`a[0] * 1e9 + a[1]` comes to mind as a naive approach), you should also be aware of the precision limits of JavaScript numbers -- there's a reason why `hrtime()` returns a tuple and not just a single number. When in doubt, when you need proper UUIDs, you should probably use proper UUIDs ;-)

Comment: Do we have other suggestions for numeric uuid!

Comment: If you need UUIDs (which actually have a specification, see http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4122), take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript . If you just want random identifiers, use `Math.random()`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I managed to figure out something that works like this (partially, on a single machine, and NOT completely validated yet). See [Is this a viable, monotonically increasing timeId in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53142164/is-this-a-viable-monotonically-increasing-timeid-in-javascript). (Note, requires Node 10 or 11, and I've only validated on Mac OS Mojave so far)

That solution will not provide a UUID, but it should produce an ID that is always increasing in value. Some other machine/process ID would have to be appended to it to make it really unique.